# Squaddie stops taking cover!

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've started having this issue on one squaddie - and only this one squaddie so far - where randomly, in the middle of a mission, he will refuse to use any adjacent cover. I move him from one piece of cover to another, and he stands there like a goof. Fortunately, he's a support, so it's not TOO big a deal. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

It's worth noting that the second time I noticed him doing this, I moved him away from cover, then back into cover, and he resumed ducking behind cover like his squadmates.

Comment: What exactly happens - a soldier moves to a spot with available cover, but does not duck and gain a bonus?

Comment: Yes. I move a specific soldier - the same one both times - from cover to cover. He moves in, he presses against the cover at the end of the animation, but then he instantly pops right back up to standing in the open, and the cover shield vanishes.

Comment: Yeah I had that too once, he then took a few bullets to the face and it wasn't a problem anymore ;) . But it happend when my guy was taking cover behind half cover, and a grenade blew the cover up.